# volume of inversions by product and month

Tags: sql

Hello to all i'm new here and working also working with SQL.

My boss is asking me for the volume of inversions by product per month i have to do this month by month for the past 3 years.
The volume is the total risk divided by the products they invest in.
This have to be my mayor marketproduct.

So far this is what i have

```
select 
            SUM (RiskAmount) / wt.NumInv as Volume 
            
from INVHEADER as gwh with (nolock)

            inner join INVDETAIL as gwd on gwh.Idinver = gwd.Idinver         
            inner join INVTYPE as wt on gwh.InvType = wt.IdInvType
            inner join MMARKETP as lg on gwd.Idmarketp = lg.Idmarketp

Where gwd.Idmarquetp in ( 1,3,5,10,18,445)

and PlacedDate BETWEEN  
            '2021-06-01'
and
    '2021-06-26'

group by 
    lg.idmarket,lg.marquetp
```

Comment: Why do you created tag for jQuery there's no any relation between jQuery and your question you can't find an answer in this case

Comment: You should include the group-by columns in the SELECT